# Swift elegant condition for dictionary with boolean values

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Sorry, by the time I finished writing the question, I noticed it didn't work because of a stupid syntax mistake... I'm posting this anyway because

- A: I think it's useful
- B: Maybe folks have better ideas...

Trying to make things a little more elegant... I have an optional dictionary of `[String:Bool]` and a String key. Now, in one condition I want to ask:

- Do I have a dictionary?
- Does the requested key exist?
- is the value for this key "true"?

*The solution:*

```
var topics:[String:Bool]?

let topicName="Pictures"

if self.topics?[topicName] ?? false {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: your solution is correct!

Comment: Please [create an answer with your solution in it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that people know it has an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `Boolean` instead of `Bool`?

This should work

```
var topics:[String:Bool]?

if topics?["Pictures"] == true {
    // you have a dictionary
    // AND the requested key does exist
    // AND its value is true
}
```

Comment: Good solution, this works :) I did try `if topics?["Pictures"] {`  and it didn't compile so I retreated to what I posted above. Why does the compiler need `==true` ?

Comment: Because `topics?["Pictures"]` returns a `Bool?` and to check an optional `Bool` you need to write `== true/false`

Comment: If i want to change like this:
 if (userFollowersArray[indexPath.row]["watcher_following"] as! Bool) == false{
                let dict : NSMutableDictionary = userFollowersArray[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary
                print(dict)
                 dict["watcher_following"] = 1
                self.userFollowersArray[indexPath.row] = dict as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            }

Answer (score 1):

A more verbose idiom that I sometimes prefer (depending on the situation):

```swift
var topics:[String:Bool]?

let topicName="Pictures"

if let topicIsSelected = self.topics?[topicName] where topicIsSelected {
    //do stuff
}
```

**Update:** The Swift 3 version of this (the above doesn't compile in Swift 3) doesn't read as nicely:

```swift
var topics:[String:Bool]?

let topicName="Pictures"

if let topicIsSelected = self.topics?[topicName], topicIsSelected {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use a dictionary when you only want to store one bit of information?

Wouldn't it be much easier to just store a set of strings? Add all strings for which you would store `true` in your dictionary. Then just test if your string is contained in the set.

Also there is no need for the optional. Just use an empty set instead of `nil`.

```
var topics: Set<String>
...
if topics.contains("Pictures") { ... }
```